# Filter by keywords via PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, keyword

I'd like to know if there is a way to filter results by keyword matching that results will display just if there are fit up to 2 keywords?

Shortly... I would like to do "YOU MAY BE INTERESTING" by using keywords ($row['TAG'])... The only condition that all keywords  are similar to or a difference of up to 2 words.
TIA.

```
$words_tag=apple, 11128gb, mjvm2ll, air, macbook, 16ghz, i5250u,
notebook, laptop, mac, **- 10 keyword**
```

> **V** $words_tag(2)=apple, air, macbook, 16ghz, i5250u, notebook,
>   laptop, mac, **-8/10 keywords**
>
> **V** $words_tag(3)= mjvm2ll, air, macbook, 16ghz, i5250u, notebook, laptop, mac, **-8/10 keywords**
>
> **X** $words_tag(4)= mjvm2ll, air, 16ghz, i5250u, notebook, laptop, mac,
>   **-7/10 keywords**

My code:

```
    $words_tag=$row['TAG'];
$arr = substr_count($words_tag, ",");

    //$words_tag=apple, 11128gb, mjvm2ll, air, macbook, 16ghz, i5250u, notebook, laptop, mac,

    $search = $words_tag; 
    $search = strtoupper($search);
    $search = strip_tags($search); 
    $search = trim($search);
    $words = explode(',', $search);
    $words_condition = array();
    $arguments = array();
    $i='1';
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        $words_condition[] = 'TAG LIKE ?';
        $arguments[] = '%'.$word.'%';
        $i++;
        if($i=> $arr-2) break();
    }

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE ".implode(" OR ", $words_condition)." ORDER BY ID DESC");

    $query->execute($arguments);   

    if($query->rowCount()=='0'){

    }else{
    echo 'YOU MAY BE INTSETENTING...';
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you are after. Pls provide some sample data, expected results based on the sample data, and actual results produced by your query.

Comment: @barmar This code is so confused, and cluttered up with junk like `strip_tags` I honestly didn't see it. Comparing to string `'0'`? This code needs some love.

Comment: hi @shadow... like you can see i would like to do "YOU MAY BE INTERESTING" by using keywords ($row['TAG'])... The only condition that all keywords  are similar to or a difference of up to 2 words

Comment: @tadman can you give this code some love :)?

Comment: By repeating the 1st paragraph of the question will not make it more understandable for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `OR` to combine the `LIKE` conditions, use `+`. The condition is `1` when there's a match, or `0` when it doesn't match, so the total will be the number of keywords that match. You can then compare this with your limit on the number of matching keywords.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `post` 
    WHERE ".implode(" + ", $words_condition)." BETWEEN 1 AND 2 
    ORDER BY ID DESC");
```